# trying to make my code printout the correct product

Tags: c

The sum calculation is fine, however, for product the numbers used creates a answer larger then 10 integers, which gives an incorrect answer. I understand that its because I am using int. But when I tried float, that also didn't work.

Can someone explain how to make my product answer able to printout answers larger then 10 integers.

For example, the expected output of 6,20,4,16,15,11,6,3,19, 18 is 7800883200 but my system printsout 72076004000

Thank you

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
    if(argc<2){
        printf("Invalid Input: filename value missing\n");
    }
    else{
        char filename[50]; 
        strcpy(filename,argv[1]);
        FILE* fptr = fopen(filename,"r");
        
        if(fptr==NULL){
            printf("File not found!\n");
        }
        else{
            
            int arr[10]; 
            int i; 
            int val; 
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                fscanf(fptr,"%d",&val); 
                arr[i] = val;
            }

          
            int sum = 0; 
            
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                
                sum= sum + arr[i];
            }

            
           int product = 1;
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                product= product * arr[i]; 
            }

            printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);
            printf("Product: %d\n",product);
            fclose(fptr);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fopen` can fail for many reasons.  You should not assume that it is because the file cannot be found.  Let the system construct the error message for you; replace `printf("File not found!\n");` with `perror(filename);`

Comment: fscanf() can fail if input doesn't match your expects.  Always check return value to see if you read the number of elements you expected (in this case 1), otherwise the val is undefined.

Comment: You forget to `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: out of curiosity, what is `INT_MAX` on your platform? On most platforms these days signed int is 32bit, meaning it cannot represent values larger than 2147483647.

Comment: 7800883200 is a 33-bit number.

Comment: ... as is 72076004000.

Comment: Yes, according to my Windows 'calculator' utility (decimal and hex capable) 7200883200 = "0x1 D0F8 0800"... Unsigned, the OP might be able to reach 0xD69A6100 (3600441600 decimal, and almost half way to the top)...

Comment: I find the particulars presented in this question implausible.  I do not believe that the program you have presented produces the output you say it does, on any system.  Perhaps a different program produced that output, such as a variation where you have changed some of the data types (but probably created one or more errors by doing so).  Please edit the question to make it at least self consistent.

Comment: Guys I figured it out. Thank you for the help. hahahah

Comment: Style suggestion. If `argc` is less than two, nothing else happens aside from the error message. Print the error, then return 1 to indicate an error, thn carry one without the code nested another layer of indentation. You can do the same with your file not found error message.

Comment: Your argument filename may be shorter than 50, if you use strcpy, you should make sure that the buffer(filename) used to  receive argument shoule be clean, which means you may need initialize the buffer with '\0'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use type with sufficient range to store your `product` (and `sum`) so instead of `int` use `long long` or alternatively `double`.

Missing an include.  Using `strerror()` to generate a proper error message.  No need to copy file name before opening it.  You are running the same loop 3 times so might as well combine them.  thsi means you no longer need your array.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc<2){
        printf("Invalid Input: filename value missing\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!fptr){
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    long long sum = 0;
    long long product = 1;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<10; i++) {
        int val;
        fscanf(fptr,"%d",&val);
        sum += val;
        product *= val;
    }
    printf(
        "Sum: %lld\n"
        "Product: %lld\n",
        sum,
        product
    );
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

```
$ seq 10  | ./a.out /dev/stdin
Sum: 55
Product: 3628800
```

Comment: thank you. But how do I make it be able to printout larger numbers?

Comment: Use a larger type, either double or long.

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr, and error messages in response to `fopen` should include the name used.  Instead of `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));`, use `fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));` or `perror(argv[1]);`. Every time an error message is written in response to an `fopen` failure that does include the name used to open the file, a kitten dies.

Comment: Although this is the answer I first jumped to as well, the output the OP says they actually get is also too large for a 32-bit integer.  Peculiar.

Comment: INT_MAX on my system is 2 GiB, and the answer the op is looking for is a little under 8 GiB.

Comment: Yes, @AllanWind, and the output the OP says they get is a different number slighly under 8GiB (and well above 2 GiB).  If they are conveying the actual output accurately, then it seems likely that their `INT_MAX` is at least as large as the output they say they get, in which case it is almost surely larger than the output they expect, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If I was a betting man, I would put money on that an extra digit was was added to 7800883200 inadvertently (so it's really 0.8 GiB).  I could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 0):

To print bigger numbers, still with an unavoidable ceiling, use the additional bits available with `double`s.

From Wikipedia:

> Double precision (binary64), usually used to represent the "double"
> type in the C language family. This is a binary format that occupies
> 64 bits (8 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 53 bits
> (about 16 decimal digits).

This answers your "how can I?" It's an exercise for you to integrate this knowledge into your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { 6,20,4,16,15,11,6,3,19, 18 };

int main() {
    double x = 1;

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf( "%.0lf * %d = %.0lf\n", x, a[i], x * a[i] );
        x = x * a[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 * 6 = 6
6 * 20 = 120
120 * 4 = 480
480 * 16 = 7680
7680 * 15 = 115200
115200 * 11 = 1267200
1267200 * 6 = 7603200
7603200 * 3 = 22809600
22809600 * 19 = 433382400
433382400 * 18 = 7800883200 // <== your sought-after number
```

There are libraries available to work with *arbitrary arithmetic* values that can be as big as will fit in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

> The sum calculation is fine, however, for product the numbers used creates a answer larger then 10 integers, which gives an incorrect answer. I understand that its because I am using int. But when I tried float, that also didn't work.

Size of an `int` variable is 32bit wide, which allows to store numbers between `-2147483648` and `+2147483647`  This makes your product to overflow producing the wrong answer.

You can try using `long` integers, that go from `-9223372036854775808` to `+9223372036854775807`  but probably with large products you will overflow that variable also.

You don't show how you use `double`s in your sample code, but you must supply `double` number to the multiplication operator, or it will use a normal `int` multiplication, producing an `int` result, and then convert the data into double (which is not what you want, probably)  But as you don't show how do you do the multiplications, I cannot guess.